# `df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")[["count"]].sum()`を実行したときに`KeyError`が発生する原因を教えてください。

Tags: python, pandas

## 実行環境

- Python 3.10.2
- pandas 1.4.1

## やりたいこと

以下の`pandas.DataFrame`に対して、`user`ごとに`count`を1週間単位で集計したいです。

```
In [1]: df=pandas.DataFrame({"count":[1,2,3], "working_hours":[6,7,8], "user":["alice","alice","bob"],
     ...: "date": pandas.date_range('2022-03-13', periods=3, freq='D')})



In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   count  working_hours   user       date
0      1              6  alice 2022-03-13
1      2              7  alice 2022-03-14
2      3              8    bob 2022-03-15
```

## エラー発生

以下のコードを実行したら、`KeyError: 'The grouper name date is not found'`が発生しました。

```
In [2]: df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")[["count"]].sum()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [137], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")[["count"]].sum()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py:1028, in f(self, _method, min_count, *args, **kwargs)
   1026 def f(self, _method=method, min_count=0, *args, **kwargs):
   1027     nv.validate_resampler_func(_method, args, kwargs)
-> 1028     return self._downsample(_method, min_count=min_count)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py:1097, in _GroupByMixin._apply(self, f, *args, **kwargs)
   1093         return getattr(x, f)(**kwargs)
   1095     return x.apply(f, *args, **kwargs)
-> 1097 result = self._groupby.apply(func)
   1098 return self._wrap_result(result)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:1414, in GroupBy.apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1412 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1413     try:
-> 1414         result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1415     except TypeError:
   1416         # gh-20949
   1417         # try again, with .apply acting as a filtering
   (...)
   1421         # fails on *some* columns, e.g. a numeric operation
   1422         # on a string grouper column
   1424         with self._group_selection_context():

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:1455, in GroupBy._python_apply_general(self, f, data, not_indexed_same)
   1429 @final
   1430 def _python_apply_general(
   1431     self,
   (...)
   1434     not_indexed_same: bool | None = None,
   1435 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   1436     """
   1437     Apply function f in python space
   1438 
   (...)
   1453         data after applying f
   1454     """
-> 1455     values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
   1457     if not_indexed_same is None:
   1458         not_indexed_same = mutated or self.mutated

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py:761, in BaseGrouper.apply(self, f, data, axis)
    759 # group might be modified
    760 group_axes = group.axes
--> 761 res = f(group)
    762 if not mutated and not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes, axis):
    763     mutated = True

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py:1090, in _GroupByMixin._apply.<locals>.func(x)
   1089 def func(x):
-> 1090     x = self._shallow_copy(x, groupby=self.groupby)
   1092     if isinstance(f, str):
   1093         return getattr(x, f)(**kwargs)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py:178, in Resampler._shallow_copy(self, obj, **kwargs)
    176     if attr not in kwargs:
    177         kwargs[attr] = getattr(self, attr)
--> 178 return self._constructor(obj, **kwargs)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py:164, in Resampler.__init__(self, obj, groupby, axis, kind, selection, **kwargs)
    161 self.group_keys = True
    162 self.as_index = True
--> 164 self.groupby._set_grouper(self._convert_obj(obj), sort=True)
    165 self.binner, self.grouper = self._get_binner()
    166 self._selection = selection

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py:384, in Grouper._set_grouper(self, obj, sort)
    382     else:
    383         if key not in obj._info_axis:
--> 384             raise KeyError(f"The grouper name {key} is not found")
    385         ax = Index(obj[key], name=key)
    387 else:

KeyError: 'The grouper name date is not found'
```

`[["count"]]`を`sum()`の後に指定すれば、欲しい結果を得ることができました。

```
In [148]: df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left").sum()[["count"]]
Out[148]: 
                  count
user  date             
alice 2022-03-13      3
bob   2022-03-13      3
```

## 質問

上記のエラーは何が原因でしょうか？エラーメッセージの意味が分かりませんでした。

以下のように、`groupby`関数を使わない場合は`resample`関数の後に`[["count"]]`を指定できるます。`groupby`関数を使った場合も、同様のことができると思っていました。

```
In [140]: df.resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")[["count"]].sum()
Out[140]: 
            count
date             
2022-03-13      6
```

## 補足

`groupby`関数を使うかどうかで、`resample`関数の結果の型が異なるようです。これが関係するのでしょうか？

```
In [141]: df.resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")
Out[141]: <pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler object at 0x7fdf73ae6860>

In [142]: df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")
Out[142]: <pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby object at 0x7fdf7180fa00>
```

Comment: なぜダブルブラケットを使っているのでしょう？ `df.groupby("user").resample("W",on="date",label="left",closed="left")["count"].sum()` とすればよいのではないですか。

Comment: 集計したい列が`count`だけでなく、他にも今後増える予定なので、ダブルブラケットを使いました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date列が存在しないというエラーです。単純に`.resample()`を使ったときは発生せず、`groupby().resample()`でかつ`on`キーワードで日付列を指定した場合のみ発生するようですね。

`[[]]`内に`"date"`を追加するとパスできました。

```
df.groupby("user").resample("W", on="date", label="left", closed="left")[["date", "count"]].sum()
```

Comment: >date列が存在しないというエラーです。
`date`列を指定していなのにも関わらず、`date`列が見つからないと言われるのが、最初理解できませんでした。
pandasが勝手に`date`列を探そうとするのでしょうか？

Comment: `resample()`のキーに`date`列を指定しているため、`date`列が存在しないとエラーになります。本来は`date`列を省略しても自動で補ってくれるのですが、`groupby().resample()`の場合はエラーになるようです。一言で言えばバグですが。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

単純にgroupby関数でuserだけ集約している=dateを捨てているからでは…